# css width fit content cancels text align center

Tags: html, css

I try to center a pragraph and give it a background with low opacity to make it easier to read over the main background.
I use

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
background-blend-mode: lighten
```

but when I add

```
width: fit-content;
```

it pushes the text to the right side of the screen and ignores the text align.

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
background-blend-mode: lighten;
width: fit-content;
```

Comment: Please add more information to your question: The HTML involved and the full CSS class, this way we can assist you better

Comment: I tried your code and it does work, but here you missed out on the text-align center.

Answer (score 6):

use

```
width: fit-content;
margin: auto;
```

to do both and center text

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say with certainty what's going on from the information you included, but here's a guess:

`width: fit-content` makes the element the minimum size required to contain its content. My guess is that your text is still centered within the `<p>`, but the `<p>` itself doesn't occupy the available width.

You can see this by adding a border to the element.

If you want to center the `<p>` itself within the available space you can use `auto` for the horizontal margins.

Snippet below demonstrates what I suspect is happening. In all 3 paragraphs the text is aligned center, but unless the text wraps you can't tell.

I've added line breaks in the text below to show that the text is centered, but the paragraph itself isn't.

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  text-align: center;
}

.fit {
  width: fit-content;
}

.margins {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>A paragraph without<br/>fit-content</p>
  <p class="fit">A paragraph with<br/>fit-content</p>
  <p class="fit margins">A paragraph with</br>fit-content and margin: 0 auto</p>
</div>
```